# Need help for scrapy with CrawlSpider

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new to scrapy and stucked when I try to extract data from multiple websites by using CrawlSpider.

Here is my codes:

```py
class ivwSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = "ivw-online"
    allowed_domains = ["ausweisung.ivw-online.de/"]
    start_urls = ["http://ausweisung.ivw-online.de/index.php?i=1161&a=o44847"]

    pagelink = LinkExtractor(allow=('index.php?i=1161&a=o\d{5}'))
    print(pagelink)
    rules = (Rule(pagelink, callback='parse_item', follow=True), )

    def parse_item(self, response):

        sel = Selector(response)

        item = IVWItem()
        item["Type"] = sel.xpath('//div[@class ="statistik"]//tr[1]//td/text()')[0].extract()
        item["Zeitraum"] = sel.xpath('//div[@class ="tabelle"]//tr[1]//div[@style="width:210px; text-align:center;"]/text()')[0].extract()
        item["Company"] = sel.xpath('//div[@class ="stammdaten"]//tr//td/text()').extract()[-1]
        item["Video_PIs"] = sel.xpath('//div[@class ="tabelle"]//tr[11]//td[@class ="z5"]/text()').extract()
        item["Video_Visits"] = sel.xpath('//div[@class ="tabelle"]//tr[11]//td[@class ="z4"]/text()').extract()
        item["PIs"] = sel.xpath('//div[@class ="statistik"]//tr[3]//td/text()')[1].extract()
        item["Visits"] = sel.xpath('//div[@class ="statistik"]//tr[1]//td/text()')[1].extract()

        return item
```

When the code is executed, return nothing. Is it the problem with rules definition? Any helps here is really appreciated!

Comment: I tested your spider as normal Spider (not CrawlSpider) and it extracts data from the start_url. So the problem seems to be the CrawlSpider rule as you already guessed. It's not so obvious to me which links you want to follow on the page. Can you edit your question and add details which href should be followed?

Comment: Thank you very much for your check. The links I like to follow is all websites of online data for different competitors in ivw-ausweisung. like: http://ausweisung.ivw-online.de/index.php?i=1161&a=o44847,http://ausweisung.ivw-online.de/index.php?i=1161&a=o44851 etc. The only differences between these urls is the numbers after i=1161&a=o...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the start_url is already a detail page where I could not find a list to other competitors I went up in the website hierarchy on level to the url `http://ausweisung.ivw-online.de/index.php?i=116` as start. There is a table with a long list of competitors.

From this `start_url` you can fetch the urls of all the companies and create `requests` directly with your callback like so:

```py
class ivwSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "ivw-online"
    allowed_domains = ["ausweisung.ivw-online.de"]
    start_urls = ["http://ausweisung.ivw-online.de/index.php?i=116"]

    def parse(self, response):

        sel_rows = response.xpath('//div[@class="daten"]/div[@class="tabelle"]//tr')

        for sel_row in sel_rows:
            url_detail = sel_row.xpath('./td[@class="a_main_txt"][1]/a/@href').extract_first()
            if url_detail:
                url = response.urljoin(url_detail)
                # print url
                yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_item)

    def parse_item(self, response):

        sel = Selector(response)

        item = IVWItem()
        item["Type"] = sel.xpath('//div[@class ="statistik"]//tr[1]//td/text()')[0].extract()
        item["Zeitraum"] = sel.xpath('//div[@class ="tabelle"]//tr[1]//div[@style="width:210px; text-align:center;"]/text()')[0].extract()
        item["Company"] = sel.xpath('//div[@class ="stammdaten"]//tr//td/text()').extract()[-1]
        item["Video_PIs"] = sel.xpath('//div[@class ="tabelle"]//tr[11]//td[@class ="z5"]/text()').extract()
        item["Video_Visits"] = sel.xpath('//div[@class ="tabelle"]//tr[11]//td[@class ="z4"]/text()').extract()
        item["PIs"] = sel.xpath('//div[@class ="statistik"]//tr[3]//td/text()')[1].extract()
        item["Visits"] = sel.xpath('//div[@class ="statistik"]//tr[1]//td/text()')[1].extract()

        yield item
```

Please notice that the base class is no longer `CrawlSpider` but `Spider`.